# Python- need to calculate a cost based on user input

Tags: python, arrays, input, calculator

I need to calculate a cost based on user input and through using an array. I have the below code, but keep receiving errors (directed towards my 'print' parentheses).

Do you know what I might be missing, and whether a better array could be used?

```
#route type
yourUserInput = input("will you use route 1 or 2 ")

finance = 1 #
if yourUserInput == "1":
    finance = 25
elif yourUserInput == "2":
    finance = 35
else:
    print("you did not enter a valid route")

print ("total cost" (cost))
# ticket type
tickettype = input("what type of ticket would you like (single or return) ")
price = 1 #
if tickettype == "single" or tickettype == "Single":
    price = 25
elif tickettype == "return" or tickettype == "Return":
    price = 35
else:
    print("you did not enter a valid ticket type")

#cost = int( finance ) *int( price )


ar= (finance + price)
#print "the total is therefore",
print ("your total price is" int(ar))

input("press enter to exit the program")
```

Comment: You are missing a comma in the `print()` statement.

Comment: Where is the array?  Anyway, try: print ("your total price is",  ar)  i.e. missing a comma between string and variable to print.

Comment: How can I add an array in?

Comment: You should [read this article](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) on how to print strings in Python.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, when you want to include more than one variable or text in your output, you add it to your output statement with a comma (,). It is similar to how you would add a + in Java in your output statement.

`print ("total cost" (cost))`
should be
`print ("total cost", cost)`
and 
`print ("your total price is" int(ar))`
should be 
`print ("your total price is", int(ar))`

Implementing an array into your code would look something like this where the two values in the array are 25 and 35.

```
yourUserInput = input("will you use route 1 or 2 ")

cost = 1
finance = 1
price = 1
list_values = [25,35]

if yourUserInput == "1":
    finance = list_values[0]
elif yourUserInput == "2":
    finance = list_values[1]
else:
    print("you did not enter a valid route")

print ("total cost = ", cost)
# ticket type
tickettype = input("what type of ticket would you like (single or return) ")

if tickettype == "single" or tickettype == "Single":
    price = list_values[0]
elif tickettype == "return" or tickettype == "Return":
    price = list_values[1]
else:
    print("you did not enter a valid ticket type")

cost = finance * price
ar = (finance + price)

#print "the total is therefore",
print ("your total price is", ar)

input("press enter to exit the program")
```

I encourage you to read https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html to gain a better understanding of Python basics.

Comment: You need to define cost in your program. It is not set to anything, so you will get an error.

Comment: Thank you!! Do you perhaps know the answer to my second question (how can an array be embedded into this code)

Comment: Arrays and lists in Python are interchangeable, but you initialize it by simply writing `this_list = []` where the square brackets will automatically indicate that you wish to create and edit a list. You can access the items in the list using its index such as `this_list[index]`
This is the document for reading up on data structures: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: where about would I implement this_list = [] within that code though? Is there a similar existing example that I can perhaps follow?

Comment: ideally I tried to implement a "sum" array but was faced with constant errors. I did try to post another separate question, but was unable to do so.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to use a list for this implementation. It seems to be working properly. What do you need to put inside of the list and calculate?

Comment: I need to use an array somewhere within the code, and thought "sum" might be the most appropriate array. I need the code to ask the user their route and ticket type and based on their responses calculate (and print) the total cost of their journey.

Comment: I have edited my answer to what I believe it is you are trying to solve. You don't need to use a list for the sum. You could use one to hold the values of price and finance